# What might be causing my Tailwindcss classes not to work on my PHP file in XAMPP server?

Tags: php, xampp, tailwind-css

I am having troubles using the XAMPP server for Tailwindcss in PHP

PHP code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body class="w-4/5 mx-auto p-10">
<?php
   echo '<h1 class="text-green-700 text-3xl font-bolder">Hello Momo!  </h1>  <a href="index.html">goto html</a>'
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Tailwind setup

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["*.php"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The code above works well on my phone using and editor called CodeSnack but when I run same code on XAMPP server, the tailwindcss class doesn’t apply to the document

Comment: Consider checking that the `styles.css` file is being served by the XAMPP server.

Comment: Please how do I do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check that the `styles.css` is in the file directory served by XAMPP. Check that `style.css` is the correct location such that the `<link>` tag references it.

Comment: They only clarification I can add is a picture of the output, the Tailwindcss classes is not being applied like a normal css

Comment: Yes please, every is setup well

Comment: Thank you all, I’ve found an answer to my bug, I appreciate everyone who contributed

Answer (score 0):

place CDN firstly in the head tag ()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).